# popup with :hover cannot be dismissed with blur()

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am trying to hide a popup (implemented as a "ul")  when the user clicks on it.
This popup is only made visible when its parent node detects the mouse :hover.

In my onclick() handler, I call blur() on every conceivable node above the DOM element I pass to my onclick() handler and it's not hiding the popup.

Here's the code:

```
 // the html....
 <ul class="ul_nestedPopups">
    <li><a href="#">Breakfast choices</a>
         <ul class="ul_nestedPopups"> 
            <li><a href="#" onclick="setBreakfast(this)">Apple</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="setBreakfast(this)">Orange</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" onclick="setBreakfast(this)">Banana</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
 </ul>


.ul_nestedPopups {
    display: inline-table;
}

 // I tried using visibility instead of display -- no real difference
.ul_nestedPopups ul {
/*visibility: hidden;*/
    display: none;
}

.ul_nestedPopups li:hover > ul {
    /*visibility: visible;*/
    /*visibility: visible !important;*/
    /*display: block !important;*/
     display: block;
 }


 // onclick handler......
 function setBreakfast(theNestedAnchor)
{
   // yes I experimented
   theNestedAnchor.blur();
   theNestedAnchor.parentNode.blur();
   theNestedAnchor.parentNode.parentNode.blur();
   theNestedAnchor.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.blur();
   theNestedAnchor.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.blur();

   // NOW, DO SOMETHING WITH THE USER'S CHOSEN POPUP HERE...
   // ........some code.........
 }
```

**The way it currently works:**  When the user hovers the mouse over the "Breakfast choices" list item, the list with the three breakfast choices (unordered list with 3 list items) appears.  When the user clicks one of the 3 breakfast choices Apple, or Orange, or Banana -- I have verified that the onclick() handler gets called, but the onblur() calls there do nothing -- the 3 breakfast choices UL stays visible.

So I'm guessing the blur() might get ignored because when the user clicks the mouse on the popup, the mouse is still hovering so the onclick handler's attempt to call blur() is ignored.

So I thought about structuring the onclick handler this way but don't think it will work and I suspect that there's a better/easier way:

```
 // onclick handler......
 function setBreakfast(theNestedAnchor)
{
   1.  change the class to a different class that has no :hover selector
   2.  then call blur() to make the popup disappear
   3.  then change the class back to the original one with the :hover selector
       to re-enable the :hover behavior for next time
}
```

Is there an easier/better way to make the popup that appears on :hover -- disappear
when the user clicks on it?

Comment: Hover has nothing to do with focus.

Comment: Sounds like you actually want to trigger a _mouseout_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hover event is for when you want something to happen on mouseover, and then to un-happen on mouseout. Correct me if I have this wrong, but what you are describing is to open the popup on mouseover, then close it when it is clicked. So you don't care about mouseout, so you do not want to be using hover.

I think you want this. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DLYwV/
You'll prob want to restyle to fit your needs, but the logic is all here.

**HTML**

```
<div id='hoverOver' onMouseOver='showPopup();'>Hover over me to open the popup</div>

<div id='popup'><br>I'm a popup.<br>Click
<a href=javascript:closePopup();>here</a>
to close.</div>
```

**JS**

```
function showPopup()
{
 document.getElementById('popup').style.visibility='visible';    
}

function closePopup()
{
 document.getElementById('popup').style.visibility='hidden';    
}
```

**CSS**

```
#hoverOver{

    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
}
#popup{
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    background:white;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

Comment: That looks promising -- I'm going to set about modifying my code to try it.